# Adding Multiple connections to same user using Prisma in Nest Js

Tags: api, next.js, nestjs, prisma

```
const studentClasses = await this.prisma.student.update({
      where: {
        id: dto.id,
      },
      data: {
        classes: {
          connect: [{ classId: CLASSIDHERE }, { classId: CLASSIDHERE }],
        },
      },
    });
```

CLASSIDHERE: I want to change this dynamically because I want to connect all the classes that can be in the database?
Is there an easy to do this with prisma? Or I have to do a loop and run the connect...? I want to know best approach or maybe better...!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry what is this?

Comment: guidelines for asking question properly

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you'd like to connect many classes with a student. If yes,
I think you can simply connect by passing an array as you described

```
const classes = {
  connect: [
    {classId: ''}, {classId: ''}, ...
  ]
}
const studentClasses = await this.prisma.student.update({
  where: { id: dto.id },
  data: { classes },
});
```